# Initialising multiple structs in go

Tags: struct, go

I need to initialise multiple struct variables

Let's say the struct is

```go
type Foo struct {
  a int
  b *Foo
}
```

And let's say I want to initialise 5 of those. Is there a cleaner way of doing it than below fragment multiple times?

```go
s0 := &Foo{}
s1 := &Foo{}
s2 := &Foo{}
```

something like

```go
var a, b, c, d int
```

Thanks for help! : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put them in one statement if you want:

```
s0, s1, s2 := new(Foo), new(Foo), new(Foo)
```

You can also do this:

```
var s0, s1, s2 Foo
```

And then use `&s0`, `&s1` and `&s2` subsequently instead of `s0`, `s1` and `s2`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you require pointers? If not, the you have exactly the answer in your question. Just replace `int` with your type in your var statement.

Comment: Sorry Dustin, you're right. The wording of your answer confused me, and I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and a slice to allocate 5 foos.

```
 foos := make([]*Foo, 5)
 for i := range foos {
     foos[i] = &Foo{}
 }
```

An alternative would be to use an array:

```
 foos := [5]Foo{}
```

and use &foos[0], &foos[1], ... as your pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred way would be to wrap this in a factory function (which you should do anyhow):

```
func NewFoos(count int) []foo {
    return make([]foo, count, count)
}
```

This is clean, concise and **soft**: Allows you to easily initialize as many or as few as you need.

Comment: There is no need for the loop. Just `return make([]foo, count)` is sufficient. `make` already constructs the elements of the slice to their zero values.

Comment: I thought about your point after I posted this - didn't get a chance to test it. At the time I thought that maybe `make`would just allocate the memory but not the `foo` instance. I edited, taking your word for it.:)